# Frequent network failure with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, networking

On my windows 10 workstation, I regularly lose the network for 5-10 seconds. I have a wired connection to the network like my co-workers and I am the only one in the office with this problem.

I noticed that this happens at regular intervals, every 15 minutes. e.g. 8:00, 8:15, 8:30... (Always right on time.) So I suspect that the source of the problem is software.

I did not find anything in the Windows task scheduler. I have the latest update and no malware was found and I did not find anything in the EventLog.

This problem has become really irritating. I don't know where to look anymore. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: When you lose "the network", 1) does Windows show the Ethernet connection being physically disconnected? 2) does `ipconfig /all` show that you still have an IPv4 address, or does it disappear? 3) do you normally have an IPv6 address (not counting "fe80" link-local ones, and does _that_ disappear when the network is lost? 4) are you still able to ping the IPv4 and IPv6 gateways when the network disappears? 5) able to ping the DNS servers? 6) able to look up domain names via nslookup? (Since it's almost "on schedule", leave a console window open so that you could check really quick.)?

Comment: It could be the power setting for the network card. If possible, change them so that it never "goes to sleep". Another thing to try as a workaround is to connect via Wifi (if possible), and see if you also get the disruption or not. You may have a faulty network card as well (happened to me before). If everything else fails, you can try to replace the card, or get a USB network card as a replacement (they are not expensive).

Comment: Thank you for your help. When the problem occurs, I see nothing different in ipconfig /all (nothing disappears).
However, I always get 2 ping "request timed out" on the gateway at the same time the problem occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several weeks of investigation, we finally identified that the problem came from a faulty network equipment. (Switch)